# Use of Class class in java

Tags: java, class

This is the question asked to me in one of the interviews,

What is the use of `Class` class, How JVM interprets if we write `test.class` in the `test.java` file.

```
Test.java

Class c = Test.class;
```

Please share your thoughts

Comment: Where is the problem? Is `test` an instance of `Test`?

Comment: Sorry bro it was a typo...Test.class

Comment: "Please share your thoughts" -> "My question is eligible for closing"

Comment: I think had it not been said that you were asked this question at an interview then it is a valid question

Comment: @TomIngram: This question has about 1000 possible answers, written the way it is. That doesn't meet Stack Overflow FAQ's requirements

Comment: @LukasEder Fair enough, am I write in my basic understanding that class objects are the basis of refelection and perhaps even introspection allowing for dynamicism at runtime?

Comment: @TomIngram: That's 2 possible, correct answers there :-)

Comment: Can we say that JVM internally uses this to load our classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Class class whenever you want want to get class related information. eg if you want if the class name is `com.example.ZiggyTest2` then perform a particular task

**Example**

**Implementation**

```
void doSomeThingOnBasisOfClassName(Class c){
            System.out.println(c.getCanonicalName());
            if(c.getCanonicalName().equals("com.example.ZiggyTest2")){
                System.out.println("Do some thing");
            }
        }
```

**Call the method in side any class**

```
Class c = ZiggyTest2.class;
doSomeThingOnBasisOfClassName(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

[The java specification 15.8.2 Class Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#251530)

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type followed by a
>   `.' and the token class. The type of a class literal is Class. It
>   evaluates to the Class object for the named type (or for void) as
>   defined by the defining class loader of the class of the current
>   instance.

So `Test.class` is the class literal, JVM will evaluate it to the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object. You can get the information  (such as its methods , fields , annotations etc) about the  Class `Test` from its [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object